# UIView background color darker than UICollectionView background color

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I set up a custom background color for `UICollectionView` using the Attributes inspector. 
If I set up the same color for `UIView` using the Attributes inspector, the background color appears darker.
Could anybody give me a reason or even a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to set the same background color for the UICollectionViewCell using the Attributes inspector. The background of the cells seems to extend beyond the cell boundaries. If you need a different background for the cells you can fill the UICollectionViewCell with a UIImage and set the background of the UIImage to the color you want.